# Как заставить NavMeshAgent подойти максимально близко к точке, лежащей за границами NavMesh?

Tags: unity3d, поиск-пути

Ситуация следующая: делаю `RTS`, на юнитах висит `NavMeshAgent`. На зданиях - `NavMeshObstacle`. Когда пытаюсь отправить юнитов к зданию - команда игнорируется, потому что точка назначения лежит в зоне `NavMeshObstacle`.
Как можно получить точку на границе `NavMeshObstacle` зоны здания, ближайшую к юниту, что бы отправить юнита к ней?
Или может есть способ как-то заставить `NavMeshAgent` следовать к точке, даже если пути к ней не существует, пока не упрется в непроходимый участок?

Comment: Я плохо знаю NavMesh, но вы можете выстрелить лучом из позиции юнита в сторону цели и отправить юнита в точку столкновения лучом с препятствием. Если луч ни во что не уперся (или уперся в объект дальше целевой точки), то отправляем юнита куда надо — ему ничего не мешает.

Comment: Рассматривал такой вариант, но в данном случае проблему не решит. Потому что на пути к нужному зданию могут находится препятствия с коллайдерами, в том числе - другие здания, что исключает использование маски слоя для луча как  решение. Помимо этого - маршрут, с учетом рельефа, может иметь не прямолинейный характер.

Comment: Из возможных "костылей" еще рассматриваю вариант навтыкать с каждой стороны здания небольших коллайдеров, по границе NavMeshObstacle, и при задании пути к зданию - отсылать агенту случайную точку из случайного коллайдера, во круг этого здания. Но как-то по-конченному это выглядит( И не совсем логично с точки зрения геймплея -юнит вместо того что бы остановиться, когда подбежал к зданию, может побежать к его дальней границе, потому что туда выпал рандом при задании пути... И логика передвижения группой усложнится - необходимо будет проверять каждую точку назначения на ее пересечение со зданием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен.
**В настройках NavMeshObstacle необходимо снять галку "Carve".** И всё. В этом случае объект не будет резать сетку проходимости, но в тоже время останется препятствием, через которое нельзя пройти.
При задании точки внутри этого объекта агенту в качестве точки назначения - он будет туда следовать до тех пор, пока не упрется в препятствие, и будет безуспешно пытаться туда попасть - этот момент уже отловлю коллайдером "здания" и буду сбрасывать точку назначения агента через ResetPath или переназначать её на текущую позицию юнита (в контексте логики моей игры - этот вариант будет более логичным, для выхода из состояния).